# AzureDevops agent must finish current build before taking an other one

Tags: parallel-processing, azure-devops

**Situation**

I'm working on an AzureDevops Server 2020 with only one agent.

I have 2 build pipelines:

- Build pipeline (yaml)
- Merge pipeline (yaml)

Each pipeline contains multiple stages that contains only one job (because each task of the stage must run on same agent).

**Current behavior**

If I run the two pipelines at the same time, the agent run the two in a "fake" parallel that make the two builds very slow.

Exemple of agent **process order**:
*build-stage1, build-stage2, merge-stage1, merge-stage2, merge-stage3, merge-stage4, build-stage3...*

**Wanted behavior**

This is not something unexpected if we have more agents than build executions. But this will never be my case.

So I will prefer to **lock the agent** for the current build (like built-in in Jenkins).

Exemple of agent **wanted process order**:
*build-stage1, build-stage2, build-stage3, build-stage4, build-stage5(latest), merge-stage1, merge-stage2, merge-stage3, merge-stage4, merge-stage5(latest)*

Is it possible to set the agent work **attribution policy** ?

Comment: Are the two pipelines both triggered on the same push?

Comment: So this is the expected outcome of triggering both pipelines at the same time, as jobs are scheduled individually and the next stage's jobs are not scheduled until the previous has finished.

If you want the merge pipeline to run after the build pipeline could you get the build pipeline to trigger the merge pipeline if the build pipeline is successful?

Comment: Hello @Dom,
This are two completely independents pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Dom.

Based on my test, I could reproduce this behavior. But I am afraid that there is no method to lock the agent to complete the pipeline before taking another one.

For a workaround:

You could use [Pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to trigger the merge Pipeline.

Build Pipeline:

```
    pool:
      name: Default
      
    stages:
    - stage: Build_Stage1
      displayName: Stage1
 ....
    
    - stage: Build_Stage2
      displayName: Stage2
      dependsOn: Build_Stage1
   ....
    
    - stage: Build_Stage3
      displayName: Stage3
      dependsOn: Build_Stage2
   ....
```

Merge Pipeline:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: TestTrigger  
    source: ABC
    trigger:
     branches:
      - '*'

pool:
  name: Default

stages:
- stage: Merge_Stage1
  displayName: Merge1
...

- stage: Merge_Stage2
  displayName: Merge2
  dependsOn: Merge_Stage1
  ...

- stage: Merge_Stage3
  displayName: Merge3
  dependsOn: Merge_Stage2
  ...
```

In this case, you could  queue the Build Pipeline alone. Then the Merge Pipeline will be triggered after completing the Build Pipeline.

The Process: `build-stage1, build-stage2, build-stage3, build-stage4, build-stage5(latest), -> Tiggeer -> merge-stage1, merge-stage2, merge-stage3, merge-stage4, merge-stage5(latest)`

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

To get this feature, you could add your request for this feature on [our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thank you but my pipeline are completely independent.
Build pipeline is started manually. Merge pipeline are triggered by PR (I can have more than 50 PR opened at the same time). You can imagine the time every PR (and the first one) will take if I can not prioritize them by FIFO.

Comment: Why I check this answer as the good one: It clarify this option doesn't exist. But I'm able to "fix" this issue using `dependsOn: []` because it will add each job into the queue and use FIFO to execute them.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because a job is not added to agent queue if it depends on something (and by default it depends on previous stage).

Using `dependsOn: []` let Azure Devops know that it depends on nothing so each jobs are added to the queue and are executed in FIFO order.